# How make intel x86 emulator accelerator (haxm installer) compatible with windows 10(32 bit)

Tags: android

I have problem that intel x86 emulator accelerator (haxm installer)  compatible  with windows 10 (32 bit) I tried to download it manually but it make restart to my computer and when I make search I found That is for windows 10(X64)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you visit this website first and check if your processor is compatible with HAXM. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005486/processors.html

Before installing it, you will have to unable vyper-V.